# Image saving in Database using Django giving Error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Tags: python, mysql, django, image

Hi I am extracting frames from video and want to store these frames into database using Django. Here is my code :

```
def saveFrame(request):  
video = Video.objects.last() 
path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
path = path.replace('videos',video.video.url)
clip = VideoFileClip(path) 
 
clip = clip.subclip(0, 15)  
clip = clip.cutout(3, 10) 
clip.ipython_display(width = 360) 

cap= cv2.VideoCapture('__temp__.mp4')
i=0
image = Image()

while(cap.isOpened()):
 ret, frame = cap.read()
 if ret == False:
    break
 image.video_id = video
 image.title = video.title +str(i)
 image.imagefile = frame
 image.save()
 print(i)
 i+=1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

When I run this code i recieve this error :

> Error in image.save()
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
> Here is my Image Class that I created in model.py:

```
Class Image(models.Model):
    video_id = models.ForeignKey(Video, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,null="false")
    title= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    imagefile= models.FileField(upload_to='images/', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.video_id + ": " +self.title+ ": " + 
        str(self.imagefile)
```

Can anyone help me with this issue so I can save images into database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Youll need to have image = Image() within the loop so you create a new image object per frame

Comment: Have you got an override in the save() function of the Image model ?  if so, post that

Comment: Yes at first I tried to keep this line  image = Image()   inside the loop but it did not work

Comment: .save() function is by default function for storing data into database provided by django

Comment: Share model as well

Comment: okay question updated, See now